# Get the previous message to a discord channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

Given a discord message id and a channel id, is there a way of finding the previous message to the same discord channel?

Message ids are intigers, and my impression is that the  are monotonously increasing. So if there was a way of looking up all the message ids that a channel has recieved, i think it would be as simple as finding the highest that is less than the id you are interested in.

Comment: See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.history

Comment: Thanks! that looks helpful. I'm not sure how to use it. Would you be able to answer with a bot that prints the text of the previous message, when a message is recieved- I think that would give me everything i want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if u meant to find the content of the message itself or the previous message before it but you can read more on txt_channel.history [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history):

What  history does is enabling you to see the message history of a text channel.
So if you want to find the contents of a specific message using it's id you can do:
(of course you need to fetch the text channel, you can look at [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel))

```
async for msg in txt_ch.history(limit=[how many messages back you want the loop to go]):
    if msg.id == ID_OF_MSG: # you found the message
       print("the message with the id has been found")
```

now this code ^^ is pointing you to the message you gave with the current id but if you want to get the message previous to it you just add this:

```
async for msg in txt_ch.history(limit=[how many messages back you want the loop to go]):
    found_message = False
    if msg.id == ID_OF_MSG: # you found the message
       found_message =True
    elif found_message:
       found_message = False
       print("previous message")
```

Of course you can change the last line on the print to something like:

```
print(msg.content)
```

to see it's content, or you can send it back to the channel, it is up to you.

side not:
I tried to test it and it doesn't seem that the ids of the messages are one after another so you can't do id-1 to get the previous message id.